# How to apply fixes to pull request after review - correct approach

Tags: python, git, github

My friend and I agreed that we will be conducting reviews for our commits to master in our project. Recently I've got some issues in my pull request, and I want to fix them and push only the correct commit to master, without the commit that has mistakes in it. How can I do it, or is there another approach for this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a commit tree similar to the following:

```
master
|   \
|   incorrect commit
|    |
|   correct commit on top of incorrect one
```

You could either do an interactive rebase and squash your commits together or you could soft reset all of your changes and create a new commit like this:

```
git reset --soft origin/master
git commit -m "New commit message"
git push -f
```

Answer (score 0):

cherry picking is the answers.

1. Choose the branch to which you want to add the commit.

```
git checkout master
```

2. Execute Cherry pick.

```
git cherry-pick <commit-hash>
```

Comment: I'm gonna try this approach too, thank you so much :)